# Is Auto-Return setting necessary in paypal website payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I have set `return` and `rm` variables, but after successful transaction the user is not being automatically redirected to the "thank you page".

Do I have to turn on "Auto Return" in my business account? I thought these are separate settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to turn on "Auto Return" in my settings. The `return` variable in the button then can override PayPal's setting. They also warn you that if Paypal Account Optional is on, it won't autoredirect.