# Paypal website payment standard not returning to return url from Sandbox test account

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using `Paypal Website Standard` integration with `Asp.Net` and my problem is even after payment is successful, paypal is not returning me to my `thank-you.aspx` page. I have already set `return-url` in code as

```
sbForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"return\" value=\"" + successUrl + "\">");
```

means, I have created form mark-up using `Code-Behind`. Success url is absolute reachable (I can copy `url` and paste in browser, it works). I have my `sand-box` settings as below:

1. Profile -> Selling Tools
2. Under `Selling Online` -> Website Payment Preferences
3. Auto Return: On
4. Return URL: `http://mywebsite/thank-you.aspx`
5. Payment Data Transfer: Off
6. PayPal Account Optional:On
7. Contact Telephone:Off (PayPal recommends this option)
8. Support giropay and bank transfer payments:No

However it return to cancel page without fail if I cancel payment.

**Edit**
Taking reference if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338653/return-url-in-paypal-website-payments), I set `PayPal Account Optional:Off` but no luck.

**Edit**
When I click the link after payment success message on `Paypal`'s success page, I can go back and debug but it not returning any `QueryString` with the key name `tx` which results always `Fail\n` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned `Payment Data Transfer` On and get it worked

Answer (score 1):

With Payments Standard, enabling auto-return with a return URL should redirect, but it can sometimes take up to 10 seconds or so for the redirection to happen.  That's why there is no guarantee users will make it to your thank you page even when it's all configured and working well.

If you need to ensure users end up at your site and there's no chance they wouldn't reach your thank you page then you'll want to use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) instead of Payments Standard.

The Express Checkout flow doesn't get completed until the user is back at your site (where you make the final API call) so you can rest assured you'll always end up on your thank you page.

Even still, if you're trying to automate procedures like updating your database, sending email notifications, etc. you'll want to use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/).

IPN's are triggered instantly, so you can automate procedures in real-time.  It also allows you to handle things like pending payments that have cleared (which you wouldn't want to deliver or ship right away), disputes, refunds, etc.

Comment: Does IPN guarantee that customer will be redirect to my thank you page?

Comment: No, IPN happens completely separate from the checkout flow.  It will be triggered the instant the transaction is completed.  Express Checkout will guarantee the user will end up at your site, though.

Comment: I used IPN, set listener in my profile but debugger never reached my code :(. any guess whats happening?

Comment: IPN is a silent POST, so you'd have to check your web logs to see what error happened when it was hit.

Comment: Following the Express Checkout API link (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_integration/) shows that that API deprecated Jan 1 of 2017.